# Parsing 'min:sec' string with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse a string containing minutes and seconds separated by `:`. Both min and secs are optional (one needs to be provided though). Here is what I expect to get from my regex:

```
'0'    // => '', '0'
'30'   // => '', '30'
':30'  // => '', '30'
'1:'   // => '1', ''
'1:30' // => '1', '30'
```

There is no need to get an empty string, it will be parsed using `parseInt(value, 10) || 0` afterwhile, so it could be `0`, `''`, `undefined`, ...

I tried this regex:

```
^([0-9]+)?:?([0-9]+)?$
```

But when there is only one value and no separator, it's considered as a minute:

```
'0'    // => '0', ''   <= wrong result
'30'   // => '30', ''  <= wrong result
':30'  // => '', '30'
'1:'   // => '1', ''
'1:30' // => '1', '30'
```

You can see the [test case here](http://scriptular.com/#%5E%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%3A%3F%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%24%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%220%22%2C%2230%22%2C%22%3A30%22%2C%221%3A%22%2C%221%3A30%22%5D).

Any idea?

---

**Edit**: 
My current implementation (without a regex) looks like that:

```
var min, parts, sec, bp;
bp = '1:30';
parts = bp.split(':');

if (parts.length === 2) {
  min = parts[0];
  sec = parts[1];
} else {
  min = 0;
  sec = parts[0];
}
```

Comment: why don't you do a split?

Comment: I'm using a `split` at the moment but I'm trying to make it work with a regex. If I don't find a solution I'll stick to my current implementation.

Comment: I applaud your search for the ideal solution, but I don't see how using a regex would improve anything.  All it will do is make your code harder to read/maintain and less efficient.

Comment: `(':' + '1:30').split(':').slice(-2)` `(':' + '30').split(':').slice(-2)`

Comment: Your current implementation looks perfect to me.  Why change it?  It's simple, it's readable, and it works.  Wrap that in a function (for re-use) and call it a day!

Comment: @jahroy: It will make the code more concise, which is not necessarily harder to maintain. Also it will make the program less error-prone, as it enforces the format of the input: he won't get `NaN`s when casting the groups to numbers for example.

Comment: @jahroy As Bergi said, it enforces the format of the input and allow to easily throw an error

Comment: @TimPetricola - Yep.  That's what he said.  I can't argue that point, so happy regex-ing.  (I am slightly tempted to debate his first point about maintanence, tho... but only slightly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont make the second group optional, wrap the colon in a non capturing group and make that option and replace + with * `^(?:([0-9]*):)?([0-9]*)$`

Answer (score 1):

Check the following regex:

```
^(?:(?:(\d+):)?|:)(\d*)$
```

[Scriptular Test here](http://scriptular.com/#%5E%28?%3a%28?%3a%28%5Cd%2b%29%3a%29?%7C%3a%29%28%5Cd%2a%29%24%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%220%22,%2230%22,%22:30%22,%221%3a%22,%221:30%22,%2220:30:40%22,%22foo%3abar%22%5D).

```
var min, match, sec, bp;
bp = '1:30';
match = /^(?:(?:(\d+):)?|:)(\d*)$/.exec(bp);
min = parseInt(match[1], 10) || 0;
sec = parseInt(match[2], 10) || 0;
```

Outputs:

```
0     -> min: 0 sec: 0
30    -> min: 0 sec: 30
:30   -> min: 0 sec: 30
1:    -> min: 1 sec: 0
1:30  -> min: 1 sec: 30
```

[JavaScript Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sV6Wx/4/).

Comment: You've got one capturing group to much in there. If you really wanted to use lookahead, it should be a simple `^([0-9]+(?=:))?:?([0-9]+)?$`

Comment: @Bergi actually, that was intentional. So the missing values would end up as empty strings instead of `undefined`.

Comment: OK, I see that. Still, the second lookahead is superfluous, and it should be simplified to `^([0-9]+(?=:)|):?([0-9]+)?$`

Comment: @Bergi Oh, yeah, sure thing. I added it there while making some tests. As it didn't matter much, I ended up forgetting it there. Thanks for the heads up!!

Comment: @Bergi looks pretty good! Actually I don't need to get an empty string, as I will parse it as a int after. I'm doing a `parseInt(match[1], 10) || 0` so getting undefined is not a big deal.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a new regex. Check it out. See if it fits or if there's something else we still have to improve.

Answer (score 1):

In your regex everything is optional, and if there is only one number present it will be matched by the first group. You will need to make the following colon a requirement for that capturing group (not being part of it, though, so use an additional non-capturing group):

```
^(?:([0-9]*):)?([0-9]*)$
```

```
var parts = bp.match(/^(?:(\d*):)?(\d*)$/);
if (parts)
    var min = +parts[1] || 0, // can be undefined if no colon
        sec = +parts[2];
else
    throw new SyntaxError("Invalid 'min:sec' format");
```

Btw, if you're using `parseInt` anyway then capturing the colon won't hurt. The simplest (shortest) one then will be just `(\d*:)?(\d*)`:

```
var parts = bp.match(/^(\d*:)?(\d*)$/);
if (parts)
    var min = parseInt(parts[1], 10) || 0,
        sec = parseInt(parts[2], 10) || 0;
else
    throw new SyntaxError("Invalid 'min:sec' format");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
^([0-9]+:)?([0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: Not bad! Only `:30` is not matched, we're getting closer!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you and that you wanted to get an array as result:

```
function parseTime(time){

  var tranfTime = time.replace(':',',').split(',');

  if(time.length > 2 || time[1] === ':'){
    time = tranfTime;
  }
  else{
    time = [''].concat(tranfTime);
  }

  return time;
}

parseTime('1:30') -> ['1','30']
```

Comment: Why don't you just split on the `:` right away? Also notice that older IEs don't support accessing single characters with bracket notation, you better used `.charAt`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer my original `split` code.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex seems to be the one:

```
^(?:(\d+):)?:?(\d+)?$
```

See [test case](http://scriptular.com/#%5E%28?%3a%28%5Cd%2b%29%3a%29?%3a?%28%5Cd%2b%29?%24%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%220%22,%2230%22,%22:30%22,%221%3a%22,%221:30%22,%2220:30:40%22,%22foo%3abar%22%5D).

Comment: ... you're right. Actually it's not such a big deal but I'll keep looking for the perfect regex.

Comment: I thought you needed an empty string. If you don't, things are much easier. I'll update mine if nobody has got it yet.

Comment: @acdcjunior Sorry for the lack of precision in the question I edited it. If you update yours even without an empty string, I'll accept it :)

Comment: @TimPetricola: There are already answers with working, "perfect" solutions. Haven't you tested user1937198's one (or mine, which turned out to be the same actually)? You should upvote and/or accept them.

Comment: @Bergi Yep you're right, it wasn't working on Scriptular for I don't know what reason but it's working well in the console... My bad.